# A blocking equivalent to Tornado?

Tags: python, django, tornado

I've been working with Tornado and have gotten very used to it's overall style and syntax. Currently, I would like to write a website (in Python) that does not require the asynchronous, non-blocking capabilities of Tornado. Obviously, I can use frameworks like Django or Pylons, but I was wondering if there was a particular Python setup that would most closely resemble Tornado but be blocking, rather than non-blocking.

Note: I've been experimenting with Django, but I feel as if it is a bit heavy-weighted for my current needs. What I liked about Tornado was its relative simplicity and flexibility while still being capable of scaling nicely should that become a concern. (Maybe I just need to keep plugging away with Django until I've become totally accustomed to it, but that's outside the realm of this question.)

Also note: I am not looking for a subjective opinion, rather, I am looking for someone to suggest, based on experience with the different Python frameworks (which I am lacking), similar design setups to Tornado.

Thanks.

Comment: How does "this does not need to be async" imply "this must not be implemented async"? Why can't you just use Tornado and not care that it performs better than it has to?

Comment: Well, I could do that; however, from what I understand, it would be best to stick with a blocking setup if I am using mysql and not taking advantage of the asynch benefits. Maybe I am misguided here, but the upkeep and maintenance of writing asych code is more "laborious" than simply using traditional blocking setup. I guess I could write blocking code with Tornado and load balance with nginx...but...ehh. I figured I would ask, and if nothing turns up, then so be it.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Tornado, but looking the at the [Hello World](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/#hello-world) example, it seems to resemble Python's built-in [`BaseHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite "minimal" frameworks are:
Flask http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/ and Pyramid http://www.pylonsproject.org/.

Big difference to tornado is that they are WSGI (hence blocking) and have lots of web-site-like plugins for the things you need to do deploying web-sites.

Flask has lots of examples around and is really easy to start with.

wish you fun

Answer (score 4):

Turbo gears 2 looks promising as it has been built on top of the experience of several next generation web frameworks including TurboGears 1, Django, and Rails

[Turbo gears 2](http://turbogears.org/#the-next-generation-web-framework-that-scales-with-you)

Answer (score 1):

I've also used Tornado and [CherryPy web framework](http://www.cherrypy.org/) looks pretty 'similar' to Tornado: very easy to use, intuitive and very pythonic too. CherryPy is blocking by default (and I think is the only way to use it). Hope it helps you.

Cheers!